# How do I unit test JavaScript using nUnit?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, nunit, cruisecontrol.net, nant

I would like to run unit tests of my JavaScript code in Cruise Control. We currently use nUnit, and I see that nUnit has a javascript library.  How do I write unit (not UI) tests in JavaScript using nUnit?

Answer (score 3):

The best way to automate JS tests and include them in continuous integration process is to use [JSTestDriver](http://code.google.com/p/js-test-driver/). It is very fast, can test your scripts in all kinds of browsers, can be easily integrated in IDE ([How To ntegrate JsTestDriver in Visual Studio](http://slmoloch.blogspot.com/2009/08/how-to-run-jstestdriver-with-visual_02.html)), and what is more important - this is simple comsole application, which can be easily be executed from nant script.

The example of solution with JsTestDriver tests is [here](http://code.google.com/p/jsinject/).

Comment: It seems promising, but how to capture results later on CC.NET and display them ?

Comment: JsTestDriver generates jUnit-compliant XML output. All you need is to register JUnit xsl in CCNET reports. Details: http://code.google.com/p/js-test-driver/wiki/ContinuousBuild

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [JSUnit](https://github.com/pivotal/jsunit). Their JSUnit Server allows you to run scriptable JavaScript unit tests within a Java virtual machine (JVM).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Rhino, which is a Javascript runtime written in Java (IIRC, the command-line is something like java -jar Rhino.jar script.js).
This is especially useful if your tests don't require a browser.

Don't forget to analyze your JS code with JSLint !